# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host

Tags: android

I know that there were many questiones about this exception but i still can't find the main cause of this exception

It falls in the following line:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

This is when i'm trying to get XML from web.
The xml is from out bank so its free and I used it before (Java swing).
Now in ANDROID it throws this exception and I really don't know why.

- There's an internet permission in the application manifest.
- I saw that maybe the problem is in the emulator - restart didn't help, and in my device it's the same behaviour.
- The full exception error is:

  `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "<url>: No address

   associated with hostname`

The xml location is in http://www.bankisrael.gov.il/currency.xml

I will appreciate if someone advice me what can I do and if there are any workaround's.

Thank, 
Udi

Comment: Does the exception really say `"<url>` or did you replace the url there?

Comment: I replaced it, But it doesn't really matter, I've tried 2 different hosts so that's not the issue

Comment: can you connect to the url via the regular browser?

Comment: Just tried, and no....maybe it's the problem?

Comment: Seems that there's no connection at all to the internet from the emulator. Can you please advice me what to do? thanks

Comment: I don't know how to solve that, never had that problem. Try with a new emulator instance maybe

Comment: OK I find that its a connection problem. emulator didn't have access to network. I tested it in other environment and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced same problem., in emulator HttpResponse working. when i execute kindle fire device. HttpResponse not worked. After added the permission its working.

Please make sure have you added permission on manifest file.

**`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`**